# Computing number of irreducible polynomials of degree n over $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

When I try to find the number of irreducible polynomials (of degree n) over a finite field I first look for the number of $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ such that $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}=\mathbb{F}_{q}[\alpha]$. And then i just divide the number of $\alpha$'s by n.

Is this always right? What happens when n divides the characteristic of the field? If $\alpha$ verifies $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}=\mathbb{F}_{q}[\alpha]$ can  $\alpha$ be a double root of a polynomial?

Comment: No. The extension $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}/\Bbb{F}_q$ is Galois and hence separable. Therefore irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_q$ only have simple roots in $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$.